# Accidentally caused "CR LF" to appear. How to remove them?

Tags: texniccenter

[image]

I use TeXnic Center, and somehow I managed to push some combination of keys that caused all these normally invisible "CR LF" things to appear (apparently they indicate ends of lines). How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've enabled "End of Lines". Disable this by following View > End of Lines:

[image]

Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.